# Loop is skipping the second input in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to fill a simple array with some characters, my loop looks likes this

```
for(i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    printf("Enter each value of the plate number:");
    scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

When I execute the loop, I this is what happens,

```
Enter each value of the plate number:A
i = 0
Enter each value of the plate number:i = 1
Enter each value of the plate number:B
i = 2
Enter each value of the plate number:i = 3
Enter each value of the plate number:C
i = 4
Enter each value of the plate number:i = 5
Enter each value of the plate number:D
i = 6
```

I don't know why I am skipping every 2nd chance to get the user input.

Comment: At the first iteration, you entered `A` followed by `\n`. That's two characters.

Comment: What squeamish sadi. Try adding `printf("arr[i] = %d\n", (int) arr[i]);` into the loop to see the numeric codes for the characters you actually got.  You'll probably see "10" after each entry (the code in most character sets for `\n`).

Comment: Thanks! both of you I get whats wrong with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
`scanf(" %c", &arr[i]);` (space before %c)

Or
`scanf("%c\n", &arr[i]);`

You have this problem because scanf keep the enter in the input buffer.